# Using IN clause with PIG FILTER

Tags: apache-pig

Does PIG support IN clause?

```
filtered = FILTER bba BY reason not in ('a','b','c','d');
```

or should i split it up into multiple OR's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I didn't find it in any of the samples in the documentation.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/basic.html#reserved-keywords)

You can get by using AND/OR/NOT

Comment: @hese BTW: I did a project on Pig Latin in College and the documentation -at least at the time- was HORRIBLE. I hope is better now.

Comment: not fully into pig, was just looking to correct some existing code.  so i dont know, yet :)

Comment: Link takes you to a 404 page. Well played! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use below udf from Apache DataFu instead. This will help you to avoid writing lot of OR.

https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/blob/master/src/java/datafu/pig/util/InUDF.java

Comment: Although PIG now has an inbuilt In operator, it can lead to stack overflow at compilation for large sets. DataFu InUDF seems to be more robust

Answer (score 3):

Pig 0.12 added In operator http://www.edureka.co/blog/operators-in-apache-pig-diagnostic-operators/ see bottom of page..release notes.  Haven't located it in official docs (apart from bare mention in release notes)

Comment: Here's a link to it in [the official docs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#boolops)

Answer (score 1):

No, Pig doesn't support IN Clause.
I had a similar situation. Though you can use AND operator and filter keyword as a work around.
like

A= LOAD 'source.txt' AS (user:chararray, age:chararray);

B= FILTER A BY ($1 matches 'tapan') AND ($1 matches 'superman');

However, if the number of filtering required is huge. Then, probably, you can just create a relation that contains all these keywords and do a join to filter wherever the occurrence matches.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this filter out everything, since you are looking to get the first field to match Tapan and to match superman at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

We can use IN clause as follows:

```
A = FILTER alias_name BY col_name IN (val1, val2,...,valn);

DUMP A;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this likes:

```
X = FILTER bba BY NOT reason IN ('a','b','c','d');
```

[more info](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#in)