# Pig filter if relation contained in a second relation

Tags: apache-pig

A common thing I'm finding I desire in pig is I'll a small relation with data like

```
A = id, attribute1:int, attribute2:double...
```

and a large relation with data like

```
B = id, differentattribute:chararray...
```

and I'll want to filter B so that all of it's tuple's have an id that's contained in A. 
I know I could do,

```
C = JOIN A by id, B by id;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE B::id, B::differentattribute;
```

but that seems incredibly inefficient. [using IN cause with PIG FILTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179165/using-in-cause-with-pig-filter) claims there's no IN clause... if not, is there a more efficient way to mimic IN with a UDF?

Comment: I think the above solution is good enough. It won't take much time to run if you have enough computing power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` fits into the memory, you may have a look at [replicated joins](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#specialized-joins) :

> Fragment replicate join is a special type of join that works well if
>   one or more relations are small enough to fit into main memory. In
>   such cases, Pig can perform a very efficient join [...]