# Filter by in pig by an existing realtion

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a blacklist file that looks a little bit like this

```
481295b2-30c7-4191-8c14-4e513c7e7577
481295a2-1234-4191-8c14-4e513c7e7577
```

and a lot of other data i am loading . 
How can i filter out the data that is already inside the blacklist?
sort of `not in` in SQL terms.
I tried using somthing a little bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179165/using-in-cause-with-pig-filter)
but couldn't make this work with a relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join` and `filter` to implement it. E.g.,

```
data = load '/path/to/data.txt' as (id: chararray);                
blacklist = load '/path/to/blacklist.txt' as (id: chararray);      
jnd = join data by id left outer, blacklist by id using 'replicated';
filtered = filter jnd by blacklist::id is null;                      
result = foreach filtered generate data::id as id;
dump result;
```

In this example, the input data will be joined (left outer) by blacklist. After that, we removed the rows which match the blacklist by a `is null` check.

`using 'replicated'` is used to tell Pig to load the second relation into the memory to speed up the join. If the `blacklist` is too big to fit into memory, you can remove `using 'replicated'`.